# Error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express and node.js

Goal: when users go to /index, if there is a specific tracking code in the url, redirect them to /welcome. The function redirectBasedReferrer does the redirection based on tracking code.

```
index: function (req, res, next) {
    // We can't cache the index because it serves different things depending on cookies.
    res.set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');
    CacheControl.private().maxAge(0).setHeaders(res);

    if (!req.imsProfile && !this.redirectBasedReferrer(req, res, next)) {
        return this.about(req, res, next);
    }
    res.render('spark', {
        analyticsURI: Settings.getSetting('analytics').siteCatalystScriptURI
    });
},

redirectBasedReferrer: function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req || !req.query) {
        return false;
    }
    var referringtrackingCode = req.query.promoid;
    if (!referringtrackingCode || referringtrackingCode != "SYBNM49C") {
        return false;
    }
    return res.redirect('/welcome');
},
```

When the code reaches redirectBasedReferrer and redirects the user to /welcome, I get the error:

> /?promoid=SYBNM49C&mv=other : Error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>   at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)

Comment: I'm a little concerned that a middleware function is returning values at all, I don't think you should have those return statements in redirectBasedReferrer

Comment: basically, when people go to /index they might be redirected to /welcome if there is a specific tracking code in the URL

Comment: Sure, I get that. But middleware return statements don't really do anything, they're callbacks so the return values don't go anywhere useful. If redirectBasedReferrer is a middleware, it can pass values like that boolean through assigning properties to the `req` or `res` objects perhaps, but not through return values.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you've somehow managed to return a response twice in the same route. It is not immediately apparent to me where that is happening, but I will say that it might make sense to return an error response to the user, rather than returning just false. But beyond this, perhaps you have some middleware elsewhere that is incorrectly returning a response to the user too soon but not ending the process, so that it proceeds to try to return a response to the user again and throws the error.

EDIT:

Now that you've updated your code, I see the error. This line:

```
if (!req.imsProfile && !this.redirectBasedReferrer(req, res, next)) {
```

Will cause the middleware to potentially redirect the user but also still proceed with the index route, causing the error.

Comment: As Ananth said, the "redirectBasedReferrer" method needs to not return a redirect to the welcome page. The redirect should be in the index route. The "redirectBasedReferrer" function is only an internal function you have created that should return true or false to the index route, which can then decide how to proceed.

Comment: Seconding this, redirectBasedReferrer seems more like a standalone function than a middleware.

Comment: to redirect, should it be `return res.redirect('/welcome');`

Comment: That line is correct. It's just in the wrong place. After returning true or false from "redirectBasedReferrer", you can then do a redirect or res.render depending on the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Biggest issue is still this if block here, but you need to change some other code as well.

```
if (!req.imsProfile && !this.redirectBasedReferrer(req, res, next)) {
    return this.about(req, res, next);
}
```

Like Sam said above, this line in the index route will cause the redirection in the **redirectBasedReferrer** middleware to send a response, as well as the **about** middleware in the body of the if statement. In fact, the code that follows in the **index** middleware would actually send a third response too via the line that follows after this if block:

```
res.render('spark', {
    analyticsURI: Settings.getSetting('analytics').siteCatalystScriptURI
});
```

When using express middleware, it's much better practice to use if-*else* blocks when sending responses, so that you will always send one response or the other, but not multiple.

```
if (!req.imsProfile ...) {
    ...
} else {
    res.render('spark', {
        analyticsURI: Settings.getSetting('analytics').siteCatalystScriptURI
    });
}
```

Note the ellipses in the previous code block. Those are also sections that you need to change a bit.

Rather than as a middleware, I think redirectBasedReferrer would work better as a standalone function that returns a true or false based on whether there is a tracking code in the url or not. So if you make redirectBasedReferrer into a standalone function which takes in just the `req` object (which is the only object you are checking inside the function), you could probably use it in that same block as follows:

```
if (req.imsProfile) {
    res.render('spark', {
        analyticsURI: Settings.getSetting('analytics').siteCatalystScriptURI
    });
} else if (this.redirectBasedReferrer(req)) {
    res.redirect('/welcome');
} else {
    res.redirect('/about');
}
```

Note, in this scenario, redirectBasedReferrer would be slightly modified from what you have now so it looks something like this:

```
redirectBasedReferrer: function (req) {
    if (!req || !req.query) {
        return false;
    }
    var referringtrackingCode = req.query.promoid;
    if (!referringtrackingCode || referringtrackingCode != "SYBNM49C") {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: FYI I assumed for the purpose of writing the example that `this.about` as used in your code was a middleware for handling an "/about" route